# LinqToDB.EntityFrameworkCore IgnoreFilters() does not disable global filters on some queries

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, linq2db, global-filter

- I use global filter from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.9 on my table Object (…HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted)
- I am also using LinqToDB.EntityFrameworkCore 3.7.0 for updating and deleting records in db.
- To disable filter on queries generated by LinqToDB as I understood I cannot use .IgnoreQueryFilters() from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (correct if I am wrong).
- In any case, currently I use .IgnoreFilters() on such queries, however it seems for me that it does not disable filter in below case.

**CASE**

- I have the following Linq

`ctx.MainObjects.IgnoreFilters().Where(mo => mo.Objects.Count == 0).DeleteAsync();`

This part “mo.Objects.Count == 0” is translated as below i.e. contains global filter still applied.

```
                SELECT
                    Count(*)
                FROM
                    database."Objects" x
                WHERE
                    **x."IsDeleted" = False** AND mo."Id" = mo."MainObjectId"
```

**QUESTION**

- Can somebody advise how to disable this filter on such queries?

**WHAT I TRIED**

1. I tried to use .IgnoreQueryFilters() but i got some exceptions as index out of range smth like that.
2. I googled and did not find anything on such exception.
3. I tried to find some docs re this case but found nothing

Comment: I found similar limitations with the global query filters. Neat concept but too many edge cases so it's only really practical if you follow the pattern behind why you selected it to the letter. For instance if you are using a soft-delete system and need to support seeing deleted data whether to do hard-deletes or just view that data based on permissions then you should declare and use an alternate DbContext for those operations that does not declare the query filters.

Comment: Will check, could you please create issue in GitHub?  (I'm maintainer of this library)

Comment: I have tried simple test with no luck. Everything works, version 3.22.0.